# How to get start and end time of each shift

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a timeshift table, where 0 means no activity (or day off) and values > 0 are different activities.

I can find the start hour of the first shift and the end hour of the last shift, but i'm struggling to find the last hour of the first shift and the first hour of the second shift.. The table should look like this:

EXCEL

[image]

Taking in account the example above, what i exactly want is a formula to determine that:

- On row 3, the end of the first shift is column S (or 14:00) and the beginning of the second shift is column V (or 15:30)
- On row 6, the end of the first shift is column U (or 15:00) and the beginning of the second shift is column X (or 16:30), and so on...

Comment: I'm thinking nested index/match or possibly frequency(), can't think of an elegant way to do it. By the way, would the first shift be definitely 11:30-14:00 (2 1/2 hours) or could it be interpreted as 11:30-14:30 (3 hours) ? Do you have Excel 365?

Comment: it can be 2 1/2 hours and also can be 3 hours straight.. depends on some cases.. I was trying fiddling around with the MAX and FREQUENCY formulas, but couldnt do it. Yes, i have O365

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach. Since there aren't too many columns, you could join them all together and use Find to get the transitions from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0:

```
=LET(join,TEXTJOIN("",,D3:AY3),start1,FIND("01",join)+1,finish1,FIND("10",join,start1),start2,FIND("01",join,finish1)+1,finish2,FIND("10",join,start2),INDEX(D2:AY2,1,HSTACK(start1,finish1,start2,finish2)))
```

[image]

Then you would need to add error handling for the case where the person worked no shifts or only one shift and also allow for the case where a shift started at exactly 6:30 or finished at exactly 6:00.

**EDIT**

An improved formula could look like this:

```
=LET(join,TEXTJOIN("",,D3:AZ3)&0,
LC,COLUMNS(D3:AZ3),
start1,IFERROR(FIND("1",join),LC),
finish1,IFERROR(FIND("10",join,start1),LC),
start2,IFERROR(FIND("1",join,finish1+1),LC),
finish2,IFERROR(FIND("10",join,start2),LC),
INDEX(D$2:AZ$2,1,HSTACK(start1,finish1,start2,finish2)))
```

where AZ2 contains a suitable character string to indicate missing data.

[image]